# stripe.customers.createBalanceTransaction is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am struggling with a Type Error when trying to implement stripe's createBalanceTransaction function. Here is the API reference for the function:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_balance_transactions/create

The error: `Unhandled error TypeError: stripe.customers.createBalanceTransaction is not a function`

The code:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.livekey);

return stripe.customers.createBalanceTransaction(
    customer, 
    {
      amount:       balanceAmt,
      currency:     'usd',
      description:  'proration'
    }
  ).then(result => {
// ...
});
```

I have ensured that the inputs to the function are valid, and that stripe is configured correctly prior to the function call. I have several other stripe API functions working properly, the issue seems to be exclusive to createBalanceTransaction

Comment: What version of the Stripe Node SDK are you using? Looks like this functionality is fairly new (v7.2.0, released in June): https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/commit/2fb3f0756c894969b27a45d0405b4b942547ce2f

Comment: Ahh great point I did not think of that. Looks like the problem was just my outdated sdk. Thanks

Comment: Glad that helped; I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CustomerBalanceTransaction APIs are only available in the Node SDK v7.2.0 or higher.